# SQL Server: Convert single row to comma delimited (separated) format

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, stored-procedures

As the title states, I need help in converting a single row of data E.g,
**col1   col2   col3 <-- This are column names**

**value1 value2 value3**

To something like

**dataResult <-- this is the column name from running the procedure or call**

**value1,value2,value3**

The requirements are that this call ( or rather procedure) needs to be able to accept the results of sql queries of any column length and is able to convert that row to a comma delimited string format. Been stuck at this for weeks any help would be greatly appreciated...

EDIT* 
Assume the unique key is the first column. Also assume that only 1 row will be returned with each query. Multiple rows will never occur.

The idea is to convert that row to a comma separated string without having to select the column names manually (in a sense automatically convert the query results)

Comment: what is the key for your values ?? ex is there id unique on your table ?? which row need captured ?

Comment: edited the question based on your comment

Comment: add sample data and expected o/p

Comment: Comma separated strings are - uhm - outdated... Why not use `XML` or `JSON`?

Comment: What's wrong with concatenating the results manually? Like `col1 || ',' || col2`?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh If I understand this correctly OP needs a generic approach for any `SELECT`. And btw: This is tagged with `sql-server`, string concatenation is done with `+`

Comment: What do you want to do with the resulting comma-separated list?

Comment: outdated however some older companies still have apparently not enough resources to upgrade their IT infrastructure so json is a no go for me :( Thanks for understanding the pickle i am in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try it like this:

A declared table variable to *mock-up* as test table. Be aware of the `NULL` value in `col2`!

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1 VARCHAR(100),col2 VARCHAR(100),col3 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('test1',NULL,'test3');
```

--This is the query:

```
SELECT 
STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',' + elmt.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
        (
    /*YOUR QUERY HERE*/
            SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM @tbl
    /*--------------------*/
            FOR XML AUTO ,ELEMENTS XSINIL,TYPE
        )
    ) AS A(t)
    CROSS APPLY t.nodes('/*/*') AS B(elmt)
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'')
```

`FOR XML AUTO` will return each row as XML with all the values within attributes. But this would omit `NULL` values. Your returned string would not inlcude the full count of values in this case. Stating `ELEMENT XSINIL` forces the engine to include `NULL` values into the XML. This `CROSS APPLY t.nodes('/*/*')` will return all the elements as derived table and the rest is re-conactenation.

**See the double comma in the middle! This is the `NULL` value of col2**

```
test1,,test3
```

**ATTENTION**: You must be aware, that the whole approach will break, if there is a comma part of a (string) column...

### Hint

Better was a solution with `XML` or `JSON`. Comma separated values are outdated...

Comment: I would love to use JSON... Only if my company actually upgrades to sql server 2016 hahaha... This is, to me, a much more simpler and cleaner solution however the other solution provided me an insight to this matter too

Comment: @INeedInsecticideToKillBugs, well, maybe not `JSON`, but XML is supported since 2005...

Comment: well..... my company DICTATES me to accomplish this task in this manner hahaha i know XML works but..... you know how some people are dead stubborn and do not want to listen to peoples advice's. Mine is such a case. Didn't want to reveal my upper managements behavior too much though

Answer (score 1):

Applay the next Approach:-

- Use [For Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) to sperate comma,
- Get Columns Names Via using  [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx).
- According to your need, select [TOP (1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) for getting First
  Row.

**Demo:-**

```
Create database MyTestDB
go 

Use MyTestDB
go

Create table Table1 ( col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10),col3 varchar(10))
go

insert into Table1 values ('Value1','Value2','Value3')
insert into Table1 values ('Value11','Value12','Value13')
insert into Table1 values ('Value21','Value22','Value23')
go


Declare @Values nVarchar(400),
        @TableName nvarchar (100),
        @Query nvarchar(max)

Set @TableName = 'Table1'
Select @Values =  Stuff(
        (
        Select '+'','' + ' + C.COLUMN_NAME
        From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C
        Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
            And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
        Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION
        For Xml Path('')
        ), 1, 2, '') 
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T
where TABLE_NAME = @TableName

select @Values =  right(@Values,len(@Values)-4)

select @Query =  'select top(1)' + @Values + ' from ' + @TableName


exec sp_executeSQL @Query
```

**Result:-**

[image]

Comment: This will break in case of a `NULL` value, you might want to add to use `CONCAT()`, `COALESCE()` or `ISNULL()` to avoid concatenation of `NULL`s. Anyway +1 from my side (Although I'd prefer *ad-hoc* SQL)

Comment: Thanks for your example! This provided some insight on what i was trying to figure out !